# What would cause the jQuery cursor to remain at 'pointer' and refuse to change to 'wait'?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery that works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on( "click", "#btnGetData", function() {
        var _begdate = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
        var _enddate = $("#datepickerTo").val();
        var _unit = $("#unitName").text();
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = true, unit = "un", begdate = "bd", enddate = "ed" })'
                      .replace("un", encodeURIComponent(_unit))
                      .replace("bd", encodeURIComponent(_begdate))
                      .replace("ed", encodeURIComponent(_enddate)),
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            cache: false,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            },
            success: function (returneddata) {
                $("body").html(returneddata);
                document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('error in ajax call to QuadrantData');
                document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

...except for one thing: the changing of the cursor to the "maelstrom" (spinning blue donutesque circle):

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
```

...only works the first time. That is to say, the first time *btnGetData* is clicked, the cursor correctly morphs from 'pointer' to 'wait'; subsequent clicks of that button perform their basic function, but without a change to the cursor.

Why, and more importantly, how can I get the browser to respond to the cursor change not just the first time?

Comment: I hate to be annoying, but didn't you just ask this (in nearly identical form) 2-3 days ago?

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't? My point is, maybe it does but it's too fast for you notice, it immediately jumps in the success function.

Comment: @Jonas: Then why would it not do the same the first time?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: The code shown here is changed based on the answer to the earlier question. It works great now - the first time - but not the second, third, etc.

Comment: Maybe the browser is caching the result of that call, so the first time it's slow and then it's really fast. Can you add a log server side to see if it works?

Comment: @JonasGrumann OP set explicitely `cache: false,` but what you said would make sense for sure

Comment: `document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';` set body cursor. If mouse cursor is over any other element with other cursor defined like button, input, textarea, etc.., you won't see the wait cursor. Could it just be your issue?  EDIT: quite silly but is it your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/zq6ocykL/  ?

Comment: Oops, that cache: false, slipped under my radar, sorry. I still I think he needs to make sure that it really isn't changing. I honestly think it's a speed issue.

Comment: @A.Wolff: No, it's the plain old wait cursor wherever I move the cursor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why, but by completely removing the code to revert the cursor to its 'pointer' state from subsequent clicks works fine - the 'wait' cursor displays while the data is being retrieved, and then returns to 'pointer' state once the data has been placed on the page.

So this is the jQuery at first:

```
success: function (returneddata) {
    $("body").html(returneddata);
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
},
error: function () {
    console.log('error in ajax call to QuadrantData');
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}
```

...and I change it to this after running once:

```
success: function (returneddata) {
    $("body").html(returneddata);
},
error: function () {
    console.log('error in ajax call to QuadrantData');
}
```

...and it works just dandy.